# Is there a way to set max_allowed_packet in PDO using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I ran across

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

And I was looking for a way to change both the timeout and the max_allowed_packet without modifying the config files nor restarting the server. I found the first one had a PDO ATTRIBUTE called `ATTR_TIMEOUT`, but I haven't been able to find the attribute for the size, the only thing I managed to find was a `MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` which seems to be deprecated. Is there any other way or attribute I could use for this?

And before anyone asks: I simply can't modify the config files.

This is the full code for the connection including the deprecated attribute:

```php
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname','','');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 360);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 1024*1024*10);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR ACCOUNTING: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Execute separately `SET @@session.max_allowed_packet := 1073741824;` in this connection. Or set it as additional connection initialization command in connection properties (not recommended - this will increase the amount of memory occupied on the server for each your connection).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it right now and let you know so you can post it as an answer!

Comment: Decrease the value set to the value really enough for your purposes - I have typed the maximal allowed value.

Comment: It worked like a charm @Akina! Thank you so much for the help provided, I wish you a great day!